# If $A$ and $B$ are any two events is it true that $P\left(A|B\right)+P\left(A|B^{\complement}\right)=1$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, random-variables

If $A$ and $B$ are any two events and $B \cup B^{\complement}=S$

Is it true that $$P\left(A|B\right)+P\left(A|B^{\complement}\right)=1 \tag{1}$$

we  know that $$ P\left(B|A\right)+P\left(B^{\complement}|A\right)=1$$  and using Baye's Theorem we have

$$\frac{P\left(A|B\right)P(B)}{P(A)}+\frac{P\left(A|B^{\complement}\right)P(B^{\complement})}{P(A)}=1$$

From this we cannot conclude $(1)$

Can any one clarify on this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general. Consider the case where $B = S$, then: $$P(A | B) + P(A | B^{\complement}) = P(A) \neq 1$$

Comment: I've seen conditional probabilities not defined when the conditioning events have 0 probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

A fair 6-face dice is tossed once. Let $A$ be the event of getting $1$ and $B$ be the event of getting even. Then
$$
\Pr(A|B)=\frac{1}{3}\quad\text{and}\quad\Pr(A|B^c)=0.
$$